# Remove div when swipe to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hi I've got follow div:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.swipe {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.swipe:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="swipe">Swipe me</div>
</div>
```

I would like to remove this div on two different ways:

- **desktop:** When I click on it, it should fade out with a little animation.
- **tablet:** When I touch it and swipe to right, it should also remove with the same animation like on the desktop.

How can I do this, any ideas? Solution should be jQuery or if possible angularJS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery `.swipe` event for mobile version and for desktop you can use `.click` event:

`.fadeOut()`
 will be hide div using animation effect.

```
 $(".swipe").on("swipe",function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(500);
 });
```

OR

```
 $(".swipe").on("click",function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(500);
 });
```

Comment: Hi, I'll try this and than write you again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but when I doesn't really work, I need also to click on it on the tablet to fade it out...Can you try it please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have too much knowledge about animations (You know find a lot of those at w3schools) or swiping I can give you the code for the desktop one.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
 $(".swipe".on("click",function(){
  $(".swipe").css("display","none");
 })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this just place this script in html file and also include jquery library

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".swipe").click(function(){
        $(".swipe").fadeOut(3000);
    });
});
</script>
```